# Как подать изображение НЕ из датасета на вход уже обученной нейросети, чтобы узнать что она для него предскажет?

Tags: tensorflow

Я обучила свою генеративно-состязательную нейросеть на tensorflow, и она выдаёт неплохие результаты на тестовой выборке. Теперь я хочу подать ей, уже обученной модели на вход совершенно "левое" изображение, то есть вообще не из датасета и узнать, что оно с ним сделает. Как это сделать?

Comment: А когда вы её обучали вы как изображения на вход подавали?

Comment: Я воспользовалась вот этим туториалом https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось проще простого, есть функция tensorflow.subtract(x, y) :)
В том числе на вход она может принять и два изображения на эти места х и у (: